# PostgreSQL generates many WAL files

Tags: postgresql

We have PostgreSQL server running with a couple of databases around 6.6 GiB in total. Growing about 10 Mb every day.

I have activated WAL archiving using a very basic setup:

```
wal_level = archive
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'rsync -a %p barman@backupserver:/var/lib/barman/company/incoming/%f'
```

Yet I see the WAL size growing very fast.

```
20160921T210006 - Wed Sep 21 21:15:22 2016 - Size: 6.6 GiB - WAL Size: 14.5 GiB  
20160920T115237 - Tue Sep 20 12:07:44 2016 - Size: 6.6 GiB - WAL Size: 7.4 GiB
```

More then double of our total size of databases. So many update are not/should be done. What could be the problem and how can we find the reason?

Answer (score 0):

That's quite expected on a heavily updated database. Every update generates a log entry for the table and for each of table indexes if any indexed column was updated (if it could not perform a [HOT update](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/access/heap/README.HOT)).

You can limit the amount of generated WAL's somewhat by using [wal_compression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-WAL-COMPRESSION) configuration option (available since PostgreSQL 9.5). And you can further (or instead) reduce amount of WAL with external compression tool, something like:

```
archive_command = 'xz -1 --force %p && rsync -a %p.xz barman@backupserver:/var/lib/barman/company/incoming/%f.xz'
```

You'd need a corresponding `restore_command` which does the opposite.